# C# メールを送信できない

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

C#(.net 4.5)を使用してメールを送信するプログラムを勉強しています。

とりあえず適当な文章でも送信してみようと、自分あてに簡単な文章を
送ろうと、下記のサイト様のコードをそのまま引用したのですが、実行時に
『追加情報:構文エラーです。コマンドが認識できません。サーバーの応答:Hello there』
とでてしまい、送れません。

http://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/internet/smtpclient.html#section2

SMTPサーバー名、ポート番号、それぞれ自分が今使っているものを入力して
試しているので、多分問題はないとおもうのですが、原因が解りません。

原因と対策をお教えいただけますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

暗号化の設定まで一致していますか？ 例えば[SmtpClient.Portプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.port(v=vs.110).aspx)を既定値の25ではなく587とする場合は[SmtpClient.EnableSslプロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.enablessl(v=vs.110).aspx)の設定が必要です。ポート465だと`SmtpClient`クラスでは無理かな…？

Comment: 早速の回答、ありがとうございます。
いつも助かります。
ポートは110です。
確かに、暗号化までは全く考えていませんでした…

Comment: ポート110はメール受信のプロトコルです…

Comment: …すみません。原因はそこでした。587でした。
修正したところ、無事に送れるようになりました。ありがとうございます。
時に、SmtpClient.EnableSslプロパティの設定は特に何もせずに
送信できましたが、特に設定しなくても問題はないものなのでしょうか。